# Steiner triple system of order 13

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

How can I prove that there are only two non-isomorphic Steiner triple systems of order 13? Any hint, or a paper where I can find the answer to this question?

Comment: As far as I know that there is no way ever to construct a general case to show that two non-isomorphic Steiner triple system of order n is non-isomorphic and if you have some problems that you need to prove that there are not isomorphic, then look at their properties, there must be some properties that would help you to prove the non-isomorphic case. Imagine I give you two graphs of 5 vertices, then I asked whether we have isomorphic between these two graphs? first thing you do is to count number of degree, if there are different, then you see that there is no isomorphic ....

Comment: .... So, property of degree can help us but it is not general case to find isomorphic of two graphs. The same happens in STS, where sometimes to prove non-isomorphic you have some properties that work with some n. Thus, you need to look and search for it